# Why torrent can't download some files via HTTP?

Tags: http, nginx, networking, bittorrent, torrent

There is a torrent file in which the web seed is configured. Most files are loaded normally, but when downloading some files (text\american.ini) the connection to the server suddenly terminates and the download stops. This can be checked if, when adding a torrent, select only this file to download. At the same time, this file is loaded normally from the browser. Because of what it can be? Tested on uTorrent and libtorrent.

Here you can download the torrent file and check it personally.

[Download](http://radmircrmp.cdn.servers.l0d.net/projects/crmp/files.torrent)

Comment: What is your conf? What do the logs say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that FileZilla, when downloading some files to FTP, changed them and the torrent considered these files different. Solution: change the transfer mode from ASCII to binary.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different kinds of Web Seeds, [BEP 19](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0019.html) and [BEP 17](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0017.html), and one assumes that the server is configured to handle working with torrent clients, your torrent has a BEP 19 link that's supposed to point to a file or a directory that has the same name as the torrent and that directory should contain the files in the torrent.

Your torrent name looks like this:

```
files/licence.txt
```

and your Web Seed looks like this:

```
https://website.com/projects/crmp/
```

It's not working because the Web Seed URL is wrong.